# Error in retrieving value of image array after setting value in image array

Tags: java

I am using following code for setting the initial 8*8 Pixels position of an image array with new value,but unfortunately it returns me the initial value. Example i have change initial 
8* 8 values of Image  array with 16 and constructed the image.
when I am retrieving that image and read first 8*8 values.I have seen that those values are same to image Array previous values.(before setting values at 8*8 Array)it means 16 is not assign to Image Arrays 8*8 block

Please Suggest me the changes I have to make in my code

```
  /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package testing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

/**
 *
 * @author pratibha
 */
public class ConstructImage{
    int[][] PixelArray;
    public ConstructImage(){
        try{

      BufferedImage bufferimage=ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\image_1.jpg"));
       int height=bufferimage.getHeight();
       int width=bufferimage.getWidth();
       PixelArray=new int[width][height];
       for(int i=0;i<width;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<height;j++){
                PixelArray[i][j]=bufferimage.getRGB(i, j);
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
           //   System.out.print(PixelArray[i][j]+" , ");
                PixelArray[i][j]=16;
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

        int[][] NewPixel=PixelArray; 




      BufferedImage bufferImage2=new BufferedImage(width, height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
          for(int x=0;x<width;x++){
                for(int y=0;y<height;y++){
          bufferImage2.setRGB(x, y,NewPixel[x][y]);
          Color c=new Color(NewPixel[x][y]);
          System.out.println(" , "+NewPixel[x][y]+" , "+c.getRGB());

            }
                System.out.println();
         }

         File outputfile = new File("C:\\img.jpg");
         ImageIO.write(bufferImage2,"jpg", outputfile);



////        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   BufferedImage bufferimage1=ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\img.jpg"));
        int height1=0;
        height1=bufferimage1.getHeight();
        int width1=0;
        width1=bufferimage1.getWidth();
        int[][] PixelArray1=new int[width1][height1];
        for(int i=0;i<width1;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<height1;j++){
                PixelArray1[i][j]=bufferimage1.getRGB(i, j);
            }
        }
        ///////create Image from this PixelArray
        int[][] RetrivePixel=PixelArray1;
         for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
               //olor c=new Color(PixelArray1[i][j]);
                int var=RetrivePixel[i][j] & 0x00ffffff;
              //  Color v=new Color(PixelArray[i][j]);
                System.out.print(" , "+var+" => "+RetrivePixel[i][j]+" PixelArray "+PixelArray1[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(222));
        System.out.println(Integer.signum(93226268));;
         Color c=new Color(16);
       System.err.println(c.getRGB());
//        System.out.println(c.getRed()+" "+c.getGreen()+" "+c.getBlue()+" "+c.getAlpha());
        System.out.println(c.toString());
        int colorint =-16645630 & 0x00ffffff;//c.getRed()+c.getGreen()+c.getBlue()+c.getAlpha();
        System.out.println(" colorint "+colorint);
        }
        catch(Exception ee){
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        ConstructImage c=new ConstructImage();
    }
}
```

Comment: you have compilation errors in this code. the variable c is tried to be accessed out of the scope it's been defiend in. People might be more likely to to help if you give them working code

Comment: Now check above code Rajeev I have Edit it

Comment: I tried it and not sure what the issue is. 16 definetely gets assigned to the 8*8 of the PixelArray. You can see that if you debug and put a breakpoint on the line just after the for loop with the above assignment.

Comment: It is getting assigned true but when i am trying to get the pixel position back it shows me the previous value. Also the image constructed shows the value is updated as the image at that pixel position is modified

Comment: Noticed that bufferImage2 and bufferimage1 have different classes for 'raster'. May have something to do with that? One is 'ByteInterleavedRaster' and the other 'IntegerInterleavedRaster'

Comment: Rajeev ..What should I write in my code?